# Disqus Comment Counts in Wordpress (php)

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, disqus

I have incorporated Disqus into my blog using the Disqus plugin.

The only issue is that the original comment count built into my theme continually shows as "0 comments". Editing this area is in functions.php, so I will need to call the comment count for disqus with php and not just html like they offer.

I'm no good with php, but this is what I have so far:

```
   /* post_meta_comments */
            if($bd_data['post_meta_comments']):
echo "<div class='post_meta_comments'><i class='icon-comments'><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>#disqus_thread">link</a></i></div>\n";
endif;
```

But doing this, the website will not load.

My URL for a sample post is: http://www.naturettl.com/setting-up-feeding-station/

This is the original code without my editing:

```
    if($bd_data['post_meta_comments']):                
    echo "<div class='post_meta_comments'><i class='icon-comments'></i>\n";
comments_popup_link(__('0 Comments', 'bd'), __('1 Comment', 'bd'), '% '.__('Comments', 'bd'));                
    echo "</div>\n";             
    endif;
```

Comment: Your `echo` statement has syntax problems. Try `echo "<div class='post_meta_comments'><i class='icon-comments'><a href=\"" .  get_permalink($post->ID)  . "#disqus_thread\">link</a></i></div>\n";`  When your string is encased in double-quote characters, escape the double-quote characters that are inside the string using the backslash, i.e. `\"`. And note use the concatenation operator `.`.

Comment: Hi - having the same issue with that still. This is the original code when I haven't tried to alter anything: 
            `if($bd_data['post_meta_comments']):
                echo "<div class='post_meta_comments'><i class='icon-comments'></i>\n";
                    comments_popup_link(__('0 Comments', 'bd'), __('1 Comment', 'bd'), '% '.__('Comments', 'bd'));
                echo "</div>\n";
            endif;`

Comment: It's difficult to read code in the comments. (I only did it because I wasn't proposing the solution to your question.) You could update your question (since there are no answers yet).

Comment: ok added there - any thoughts? thanks.